# Xamarin forms: Epubreader: System.AggregateException: 'One or more errors occurred

Tags: xamarin.forms, epub

I am using [epubreader](https://github.com/vers-one/EpubReader) **(vers-one)** NuGet package for parsing .epub files.

My Code:

```
string fileName = "SampleEPUB.epub";
var assembly = typeof(MainPage).GetTypeInfo().Assembly;
Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream($"{assembly.GetName().Name}.{fileName}");
EpubBook epubBook = EpubReader.ReadBook(stream);
foreach (EpubNavigationItem chapter in epubBook.Navigation)
{
    chapterDetails.Add(new ChapterDetails() { title = chapter.Title, htmlData = chapter.HtmlContentFile?.Content, subChapters = chapter.NestedItems });
}
```

For testing purposes, I have added the epub files on the project and parse the chapters like above. I need to change this implementation.

I am able to get the epub file links stored in our database. Now I need to parse the chapters of epub from the link. But when I use the link as the `fileName` in the above code I am getting the below exception:

> System.AggregateException: 'One or more errors occurred. (Value cannot be null.Parameter name: stream)'

How can I solve this issue? One sample link is [here](http://catholic-brain.s3.amazonaws.com/qa/dc/cbrain-app/files/doc-lib/2020/07/21/08/58/27/496/head/Alices-Adventures-in-wonderland.epub). I have added a sample project [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Xpa1uP2gEqimk9hekKAYYL93r40Rz0if/view?usp=sharing) having .epub file links for the reference (epub file links are commented in the sample).

Comment: it seems fairly obvious that `GetManifestResourceStream` is returning a null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> System.AggregateException: 'One or more errors occurred. (Value cannot be null.Parameter name: stream)'

The `GetManifestResourceStream` method is used to access the **embedded** file which should be placed in shared project for the Xamarin.Forms project. The code doesn't works for the file comes from a database. You could debug to get that the stream is null because the fileName doesn't exist in the project.

```
Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream($"{assembly.GetName().Name}.{fileName}");
```

In your condition, it just needs to get the stream from the url. Try to use the following code to get the stream.

```
Stream stream;
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)aRequest.GetResponse();

stream = response.GetResponseStream();
```